# Find all non-negative integers $n,k$ such that ${n \choose k }=143$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How does one find all non-negative integers $n,k$ such that ${n \choose k}=143$?

I factorized into $143=11 \cdot 13$, which means that $11 \cdot 13=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, which implies that $n!=11 \cdot 13 \cdot k!(n-k)!$. This means that $13 \mid n!$, and if one thinks about the definition of factorial for a while, and due to the fact that $13$ is prime, we see that this implies $n \geq 13$. I'm stuck here though. Any ideas?

Comment: ${143\choose 1}=143={143\choose 142}$.

Comment: The possible  biggest $n$ is clearly $143$. Now try everything below that (kidding).

Comment: @vadim123: I'm fully aware of that. What I'm looking for is a way to find **all** solutions and proving they are the only solutions.

Comment: look in pascal triangle to find 143 , then you will have the combination

Comment: I checked all possibilities with a program, the only ones are the one vadim123 listed.

Comment: Except for $n=143$, we need the "small" $k$ to be $\ge 2$. Note that $\binom{20}{2}$ is already too big. Because of the $11$ we then need the small $k$ to be $\ge 3$. Then $\binom{13}{3}$ is already too big.

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to assume by symmetry that $k \le n-k$. We have already seen that for $k=1, {143 \choose 1}=143$.  If $k=2,$ we need $\frac 12n(n-1)=143$ and you can't get factors of both $13$ and $11$ for $n \lt 143$, so there are no solutions.  For $n=3$, we need $\frac 16n(n-1)(n-2)=143.$  We can get the factors $11,13$ we want at $n=13$, but ${13 \choose 3}=286$  Similarly $k \ge 4$ fails, so we have them all.