# Finding n and k that satisfies ${n \choose k} = 517 $

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How do I find **all** the integers n and k that satisfies ${n \choose k} = 517 $ ? How do I approach this question?

Comment: Closely related: [Find all non-negative integers $n,k$ such that ${n \choose k }=143$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041517/find-all-non-negative-integers-n-k-such-that-n-choose-k-143)

Answer (score 11):

The idea is to use the fact that for each $n$, the binomials $\binom{n}{0},\ldots,\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ form an increasing sequence. We can assume that $k \leq n/2$. If $k \geq 2$ then $\binom{n}{k} \geq \binom{n}{2}$, and so, since $\binom{33}{2} = 528$, we must have $n \leq 32$. Checking $\binom{n}{k}$ for *all* $n \leq 32$, we find no solution. Hence we are left only with the trivial solutions
$$ \binom{517}{1} = \binom{517}{516} = 517.$$
In fact, as Jorge Fernández correctly mentions, since the prime 47 is a factor of 517, we must have $n \geq 47$, and so no checking is needed.

Comment: Effective, do you think we can exploit $517$ is a semiprime?

Comment: Wait, since $517$ is $47*11$ we need $n\geq47$, so we don't need to check any of those cases. With this your solution needs no further computations.+1

Answer (score 4):

In general, finding the number of times that a number appears in Pascal's triangle is a difficult problem. There's an open problem called [Singmaster's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture) that relates to the multiplicity of entries in the triangle.

---

There are clearly at least two pairs: $$\binom{517}{1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \binom{517}{516}$$

---

After the $517^\text{th}$ row in Pascal's triangle, *every* non-$1$ entry is greater than $517$, so there are a finite number of entries we can check, so it's definitely not *that* difficult of a problem. I'll try to write some code to check if there are any other pairs.

EDIT: @YuvalFilmus noticed that we can dramatically reduce the number of entries we need to check for non-trivial solutions to $n \leq 32$. @JorgeFernández finished the beast with $$47 \text{ prime, }\,\,\,47 > 32 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 47 \not\mid \binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: No it isn't. Yuval proved $n\leq32$. But if $n\leq 32$ There are no factors of $47$ and we are done.

Comment: @JorgeFernández That makes sense. Yuval just said check $\binom{n}{k}$ for all $n \leq 32$. That's a slick finish, +1

Answer (score 4):

- ${n \choose 0}$ is always 1, there is no solution
- ${n \choose 1} = n$, which gives the solution ${517 \choose 1}$
- ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, which leads to the $n^2-n-1034=0$ quadratic equation, which doesn't have an integer solution.
- ${n \choose 3} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$. But ${15 \choose 3}=455$, and ${16 \choose 3}=560$, so there is no solution again.
- Similarly, hogy ${n \choose 4}$, we got ${12 \choose 4}=495$ and ${13 \choose 4}=715$.
- For ${n \choose 5}$, ${11 \choose 5}=462$ and ${12 \choose 5}=792$. Here is no solution, too.
- For ${n \choose 6}$, ${11 \choose 6}=462$ (just as above), but ${12 \choose 6}=924$.
- From this point on, if we found a solution ${n \choose k}$, we had to also find it before. (Why?)

Thus the only solutions are ${517 \choose 1}$ and ${517 \choose 516}$.

Comment: Nice numerical check, +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thank you!